# Handling multiple versions of same repo

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, npm, package.json

I'm currently building a library of react components which I am using in my own downstream applications.

I import these in my downstream applications through `package.json`

However I came across a thought about how to handle versioning and was unsure how to proceed.

Say version 2.0.0 breaks version 1.0.0 for `<SomeComponent/>`. A downstream application wants to use a component from 2.0.0 but let's say this application is currently using the `<SomeComponent/>` from version 1.0.0 that breaks compatibility. In this scenario, the application can't just update the `package.json`.

So how would I be able to use SomeComponent from 1.0.0 while also using DifferentComponent from 2.0.0?

What is the recommended approach for resolving this type of scenario?

I have considered making a new repo for every single component but that seems like an inappropriate overkill solution. It would rquire so many duplicate files: ie. build scripts, readmes, config files, etcwebpack configs, etc etc.

Any help or advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the best solution, but I have made dual releases before to bring in new features for older releases.

Say you have 1.0.0 and 2.0.0 and you add a new feature and release 2.1.0

If that new feature doesn't conflict with the functionality of 1.0.0, or can be resolved, then you can cherry pick the range of commits from the 2.1.0 release or feature branch.

```
git checkout -b 1.1.0rc 1.0.0
git cherry-pick <SHA..range from 2.1.0>
# execute test suites
git tag 1.1.0
```